# Rails engine: render parent application layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-engines

Here I want to render the layout of engine's parent application, i.e. in hierarchy engine's parent application.html.erb should be higher. But since engine has also got application.html.erb it is only rendering it and not rendering engine's parent application.html.erb.

How can i render my parent application.html.erb along with my engine application.html.erb

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your engine controller you can use:

```
layout 'application'
```

in order to render the application layout or you can switch to:

```
layout 'engine_name/application'
```

to load the engine's layout.

I don't know if you can load them both (engine layout should only inherit from application layout and extend it) but I hope it gets you further at least.

Comment: i got it, but one more doubt, in my application.html.erb i have used <%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>, if path extends from engine, it shows eror "undefined local variable or method `destroy_user_session_path"
how to resolve it

Comment: @ParitoshSingh you would solve that by referring to `engine. destroy_user_session_path` rather than just `destroy_user_session_path` where `engine` is the name of your engine.

Comment: @StefanMagnuson the application layout in my example is used by a lot of routes and I can't modify the variable to `engine.my_var`, is there another way of reusing the host's application layout?